# Error in Index.php and error 28 on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Need a help with the error. I have the Wordpress running on synology. There a error occur kinda weird that happen.

The REST API is one way that WordPress and other applications communicate with the server. For example, the block editor screen relies on the REST API to display and save your posts and pages.

When testing the REST API, an error was encountered:

> REST API Endpoint: https://www.okahama.com/index.php?rest_route=%2Fwp%2Fv2%2Ftypes%2Fpost&context=edit
> REST API Response: (http_request_failed) cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Haven't touched anything just in case.

Comment: Based on the given information it's not possible to identify your problem. Have a look at this documentation how to handle your error: https://www.bluehost.com/blog/how-to-fix-curl-error-28-connection-timed-out-in-wordpress/#:~:text=The%20PHP%20library%20offered%20by,within%20a%20specified%20time%20period.